Neumann Greens function for the exterior of a ball.
I would like some clarification on the Neumann Green's function for the following Poisson problem:
$\nabla^2\phi(x) = f(x) \;\;\;\; x\in R^2/ B(0,1)$
$\hat{n} \cdot\nabla\phi = 0 \;\;\;\; x\in  \partial B(0,1)$
where $B(0,1)$ is the a unit ball centered at the origin. I understand the Neumann Green's function must satisfy $\nabla_y^2 G(x,y) = \delta_x - \frac{1}{|\Omega|}$ as per this question. An explicit solution can be found in Partial Differential Equations by Emmanuele DiBenedetto for the interior problem and it reads
$G(x,y) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \left(\mathrm{log}|x-y|   + \mathrm{log}|\frac{x}{|x|^2}-y||x| \right) -\frac{|y|^2}{4 \pi}$
The first conceptual difficulty I have is that in an unbounded domain $\frac{1}{|\Omega|} \to 0$. Does that mean that there is no Green's function that can satisfy the compatibility criterion for the exterior Poisson problem
$\int \nabla^2_y G(x,y) dV(y) = \int \hat{n}_y \cdot\nabla_y G(x,y) dS(y)$
since the LHS is equal to $1$ and the RHS to $0$.
Ignoring this for now, we should be able to apply the Kelvin transform to the Green's function above to get solution on the exterior of the of the unit ball. Indeed, this gives a Green's function that satisfies $\hat{n}_y \cdot\nabla_y G(x,y) = 0$ but its laplacian is not constant and decays with $|y|^4$ due to that third term in the Greens function. Is there a different method to recover the exterior Poisson Greens function for this problem? Or is there a theorem somewhere that says this is impossible.
Any clarifications here would be much appreciated.
